# When the update occurs on Android TV, canvas seems to expand

Tags: android-canvas, android-tv, closed-captions

I'm implementing closed capture, and when I first boot the tv, it comes out well, but when an event such as changing the channel, text didn't come out.

For confirmation, I drewRect (0, 0, 1f, 1f, paint). At first, it came out so small that you couldn't see a square, but when the same event happened, it was drawn by filling half of the screen. That's why I thought it was drawing in a strange place, not on the screen. I also checked the coordinates and size of the canvas, but it hasn't changed. If you know the cause of the problem or how to solve it, please reply. Thank you.

Comment: I had a problem getSurface after update. I found the reason in adb shell command "dumpsys SurfaceFlinger".